# WordPress Permalinks Issue on Amazon Web Services

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, permalinks

I have a weird issue with my permalinks in wordpress hosted on AWS.

When I navigate to the first post located at http://civicasoft.com/news/

In my browser it shows a nice permalink for the first post of: http://civicasoft.com/granicus-acquisition/

But when I copy and paste the url from my browser it gives me this ugly one: http://civicasoft.com/%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BCgranicus-acquisition/

Any ideas what is going on? Everything looks fine from the admin.. If I type in the nice looking url it says page not found.. I have to paste in the ugly one.

I am at my wits end. I have never had these issues with a wordpress install before.

```
######BEGIN SwiftSecurity######

######END SwiftSecurity######

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Strange. Can you include what's in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I can try to track it down. This is a client site.. It only popped up on the last post they added to the site.

Comment: I added the HTA access file to the original post

Comment: See the attached HTA access file @ajtrichards

Comment: That's really wierd. I've never seen it before. The characters that it's encoding aren't usual characters either. http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I figured out what the issue was. It turns out my client had copied the title of the press release from a PDF and that brought weird character encoding into Wordpress for some reason. I figured this out after numerous trial and error attempts including multiple attempts recreating the post.